# How to detect touch support in Firefox Mobile (Android, Fennec 7.0.1)

Tags: javascript, android, html, firefox

Fennec 7.0.1 seems to support touch events, but known methods suchs as

```
var hasTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window
```

and Modernizr.touch fails to detect the support. This

```
window.ontouchstart = handler
```

will anyway yield the events.

How could I feature detect the support?

I have also tried these
http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html
and they all report false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that testing `TouchEvent in window` should work.

Failing that, testing `document instanceof DocumentTouch` will definitely work at the moment.  And starting with Firefox 9 `"ontouchstart" in window` will do the right thing, so at that point you don't care whether `DocumentTouch` sticks around.

Comment: Thanks! Testing for DocumentTouch works! http://jsbin.com/axodeb/2/edit#javascript,html